# Filebeat vs Java logging appenders

Tags: java, docker, logstash, logback, filebeat

We will start deploying our java applications using docker on AWS elasticbeanstalk, we want centralized logging and will be using ELK stack.

I would like keep one process per container, therefore avoid using filebeat, but in order to do that we would have to use a different appender like syslog or even a tcp appender.

We can't afford losing logs.

Filebeat provides retrial logic out of the box, but introducing it into the mix would increase deployment complexity, would need to make sure filebeat receives SIGTERM when containers are terminated, make sure it's pre-baked into container image or in the Dockerfile, and so on.

If we go down the path using tcp or syslog appender, retrial is up to us, and we want avoid complexity on our code too.

What are the pros and cons of each approach, in addition to what I've pointed?

Our logging library is logback.

Answer (score 2):

I have the same concerns as you. The safest way to log is a local file (assuming you have enough space). Because it is much harder to guarantee another process or network endpoint availability.

Look to discussion in Logback mail list: [orig](http://mailman.qos.ch/pipermail/logback-user/2017-June/004905.html) / [MarkLogic mirror](http://markmail.org/search/?q=list%3Ach.qos.logback-user#query:list%3Ach.qos.logback-user+page:1+mid:4ufde36qsnvnha3g+state:results)
/ [Nabble mirror](http://logback.10977.n7.nabble.com/Log-events-delivery-guarantee-td15761.html) and particularly to replay:

> If you absolutely want to be sure that logs are recorded, to the extent that a failure to log should mean the transaction should be retried then log back is not he right choice of API.

https://github.com/internetitem/logback-elasticsearch-appender project provides an appender to high available ElastichSearch cluster directly with a buffering of log events into memory if all nodes are down.

Alternative way is to write to a high available middleware for caching and delivery guarantee. Like Kafka, Redis, Fluentd, Logstash etc.